# Firebase pagination and filtering at the same time in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, filter, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I have a collection of offices that I can query from Firebase (Cloud Firestore) and then I need to only show offices that are within certain distance (let's say 20 miles) from the user. I cannot use db.collection('offices').where(...) for this query.

I have to query all the offices and then calculate the distance of each office from the current user and if it's less than 20 miles, I list the offices for the user. But the problem is that I might have millions of offices in my collection and that means for each user, I read millions of data to display maybe only less than 100 offices that are going to be within 20 miles of him/her.

2 questions here - 1) How can I perform this query without having to read all the documents in this collection. 2) How can I paginate the results so that even if there are 100 offices that fall within the desired distance, I still want to show in batches of 10 (fetch the first 10 filtered documents, once user scrolls to the end, fetch the next 10 and so on).

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire

Comment: Thanks for this. Just one question. When I query the geo data using 

"geo.collection(collectionRef: collectionReference) .within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field)", 

it doesn't count as document reads. Right?

Comment: Also, do you know how I can combine this query with a normal firebase query (using ref.where) to get offices within 20 miles where the value for "open" field is true?

Comment: If you have other questions, you should post them separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use geolocator package to store latitude and longitude of the offices and then use the where clause to filter the location.
This post contains how to implement the geolocator package:
[Obtain coordinates from an address flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62399236/obtain-coordinates-from-an-address-flutter)

After you get and save the geolocators of each offices you can query it with two where clauses like so:

```
// Get user's latitude and longitude from current location and then 
var lat = userLatitude;
var long = userLongitude;

Firestore.instance
    .collection('addresses')
    .where('latitude', isLessThanOrEqualTo: lat)
    .where('longitude', isLessThanOrEqualTo: long)
    .getDocuments()
    .then(snapshots => {
      // Do Stuff here
    });
```

Comment: I don't think this would give me the result I want. I want offices within 20 miles radius of a user!  Your solution is going to give me all the offices to the south and west of user's location I guess!